# stale element exception without using WebElement

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am getting a stale element exception. This is usually easy to solve. I just need to create the WebElement object again. But thnis time I have no WebElement at all. I am just trying to get information form the browser's console:

```
public void fillInConsole(String data){
    GenericFunctions.waitForSeconds(20);
    JavascriptExecutor jsExecutor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    dataObject = jsExecutor.executeScript("return " + data + " ; ").toString().toLowerCase();
}
```

This is the error message I get:

org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: stale element not found
(Session info: chrome=116.0.5845.188)
For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.html
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'BCNCZXM893', ip: '192.168.1.12', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_202'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 116.0.5845.188, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 116.0.5845.96 (1a3918166880..., userDataDir: C:\Users\mbormann\AppData\L...}, fedcm:accounts: true, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:57313}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, proxy: Proxy(), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:extension:credBlob: true, webauthn:extension:largeBlob: true, webauthn:extension:minPinLength: true, webauthn:extension:prf: true, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
Session ID: de6622e6242a28810845580472d51c05
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.executeScript(RemoteWebDriver.java:489)

Does anyone have an idea, what is going on here. This worked fine for a year and suddenly it's broken.